# How to execute the function return the value to called function across node js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, callback

I have 3 node js files :

1. mysqlconnection.js to store the database connection properties:

   ```
   var mysql = require('mysql');
   var cjson = require('cjson');
   var yaml_config = require('node-yaml-config');

   // project files
   var config = yaml_config.load(__dirname + '/billingv2.yaml');


   exports.execute = function(callback){

       var connection = mysql.createConnection(
           {
             host     : config.host,
             user     : config.user,
             password : config.password,
             database : config.database,
           }   
       );
       connection.connect();

       return callback(null,connection);   
   }
   ```
2. subscriptionRestService.js to handle the REST api calls:

   ```
   var express = require('express');
   var app = express();

   app.use(express.bodyParser());
   var fs = require('fs');
   // Project files
   var mysql = require('./mysqlRestService.js');
   // Get Resource Subscription data by Resourceuri
   app.post('/pricingdetails', function(req, res) {

       var workload = req.body;
       if(workload.elements && workload.elements.length > 0)
       {
           var arr = [];
           for(var index in workload.elements)
           {
               arr[index] = workload.elements[index].uri;
           }

           var resourceIdentifiers = arr.join(',');
       }
       console.log(resourceIdentifiers);
       mysql.getPricingDetail(function(resourceIdentifiers,callback){

       });

   });
   ```
3. mysqlRestService.js to handle mysql queries/stored procedures:

   ```
   // packages
   var mysql = require('mysql');
   var cjson = require('cjson');
   var fs = require('fs');
   var yaml_config = require('node-yaml-config');

   // project files
   var dbconnection = require('./mysqlconnection');
   exports.getPricingDetail = function (resourceIdentifiers,callback){
       console.log('entered into mysql function');
       console.log(resourceIdentifiers);
       var pricingDetail = {};
       dbconnection.execute(function(err,response){

           if(err){
               throw err;
               }
           else 
               { 

                   var selectqueryString = "call SP_ExposePricingDetailforUI('" + resourceIdentifiers + "')";
                   response.query(selectqueryString, function(err,pricingDetail){
                   if(err) {   
                       throw err;          
                   }
                   else 
                   {
                       console.log(pricingDetail);
                       pricingDetail = pricingDetail;

                   }
                   });
               }

       });

       //console.log('printing pricing details');
       //console.log(pricingDetail);
   };
   ```

problems faced

1. Unable to send the variable `resourceIdentifiers` from subscriptionRestService to mysqlRestService.js
2. Unable to return the `pricingdetail` from mysqlRestService.js to calling function in  subscriptionRestService.

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Comment: This isn't directly related to your question but it could help the problem that you are having.  It looks like you are kind of implementing connection pooling.  https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#pooling-connections.  Pooling makes it as simple as `pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) { connection.query(..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unable to send the variable resourceIdentifiers from subscriptionRestService to mysqlRestService.js

Well, you didn't send it. It currently is a parameter of your callback function in the invocation, not an argument for the parameter of `getPricingDetails`. Use

```
mysql.getPricingDetail(resourceIdentifiers, function callback(result){
    // use result here
});
```

> Unable to return the pricingdetail from mysqlRestService.js to calling function in subscriptionRestService.

I've got no idea what `pricingDetail = pricingDetail;` was supposed to do. You have to call (invoke) back the `callback` here! Use

```
callback(pricingDetail);
```